# The images from list in another dart file won't be display on the output, what is the solution?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the images that are from list in another dart file but it won't display anything
instead it shows the loading icon, however I used (future, futurebuilder, expended and builder in listview.builder )
As shown in the code !!
Whatever I tried it showed an exception as followed *a little piece of it*:
(RenderFlex children have non-zero flex)

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getimages(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 500,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  List reslist = snapshot.data;
                                  children:
                                  [
                                    Card(
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                reslist[index].toString(),
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                width: 500,
                                                height: 500,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      elevation: 10,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ];
                                  return Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                }),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }),
      ),
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full exception? Where it is also coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `children` from the `ListView.builder`, and the `Card` should be returned instead of a `CircularProgressIndicator`. `children` is needed for `ListView` not its `builder` variant.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're returning a `CircularProgressIndicator` instead of `Card` just do the following changes to your code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getimages(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 500,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            List resList = snapshot.data;
                            return Card(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        resList[index].toString(),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        width: 500,
                                        height: 500,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ),
                              elevation: 10,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }),
      )
```